# simultaneos equations help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

$  a \frac{b}{d} + bz    =  c\frac{b}{d} N $

$ N + \frac{b}{d} + z = A $

I am trying to solve this for z , but i seem to get a very large and messy answer when it should be

$  z = \frac{c}{ c+d}  ( A - \frac{b}{d} -\frac{a}{c} )$

can someone show me how to get this ? thank you

[image]

Comment: Is $a \frac bd$ meant to be $\frac{ab}{d}$ or $a+\frac bd$?

Comment: I added a picture of the solution my teacher gives, can you see from this where they get it ?

Comment: It would be better if you post *your work* or attempt and explain what it is you don't understand in your teacher's solution.  How far along to you understand it/where do you hit a "block"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get your "final answer" by doing the following:

From the second equation:

$$
z= A-N-\frac{b}{d}
$$

Rewrite N in the first equation as:

$$
N = \frac{a}{c}+\frac{zd}{c}
$$

Substitute:

$$
z= A-N-\frac{b}{d} = A - \left(\frac{a}{c}+\frac{zd}{c}\right) - \frac{b}{d}
$$

Doing some algebra and simplifying you can get:

$$
z+\frac{zd}{c} = A-\frac{a}{c}-\frac{b}{d}
$$

or

$$
z\left(1+\frac{d}{c}\right) = A-\frac{a}{c}-\frac{b}{d}
$$

Can you proceed from here?